# What's wrong with this asp.net markup?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<%# Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("Posted")).ToShortDateString() %>
```

It tells me `Invalid Expression term ')'`.  The code still runs fine though, it's just annoying.

This is the full markup:

```
<p>
Last Updated:
<%# Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("Posted")).ToShortDateString() %>
</p>
```

Comment: Ben, How do you did you put the grey background around the error message.

Comment: Alright, I will remember that.

Comment: Edit your post and you can see the exact markdown he used

Comment: @Bob - Thanks I just took a look.

Comment: Do you have that block surrounded in quotes?

Comment: I will update it with the full markup.

Comment: Funny thing is, I have this code in another place and it is not complaining.  Could Visual Studio just be acting stupid in this case, because it looks right to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried deleting it and retyping it out (not copy and paste)?

This sometimes works for me when I get obviously incorrect errors in the editor.

Comment: Thanks, I pretty much did that and it is not complaining.